# Android - Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when syncing gradle:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'

Possible causes:

Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
```

I already have the plugins applied in my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application" 
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react" 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and in my top level build.grade

```
plugins{ 
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '2.0.0-Beta4' apply false      
  id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '2.0.0-Beta4-1.0.17' apply false  
}
```

As shown above, I've already added the plugins to the build.gradle files and upgraded my AGP to the latest version (8.2.1)

Comment: i ended up switching to ksp instead of kapt, which seems to be the newer and recommended solution. added these lines in build.gradle

`apply plugin: 'com.google.devtools.ksp'`


`id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '2.0.0-Beta4-1.0.17' apply false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up switching to ksp instead of kapt to get this working, which seems to be the newer and recommended solution. added these lines in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
```

```
plugins{
...
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '2.0.0-Beta4-1.0.17' apply false
}
```